# vb.net basics, How do I create a public function for handling dynamically created buttons

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to vb.net. To be honest I've only been using it for a week or so. I've actually hit a wall when it comes to creating a Public Function for dynamically created buttons.

I've got a form in which I've got the following button creation code:

```
'Function for creating buttons
Public Sub CreateNewButton(font As String, x As Integer, y As Integer,
                           width As Integer, height As Integer,
                           name As String, text As String,
                           menu_type As Integer,
                           Optional hidden As Boolean = True,
                           Optional centered As Boolean = False)

    'Create a button as an entity
    Dim btn As Button = New Button
    'Assign the location
    If centered = True Then
        btn.Location = New Point(x - width / 2, y - height / 2)
    Else
        btn.Location = New Point(x, y)
    End If
    'Assign other variables from function parameters
    btn.Name = name
    btn.Text = text
    btn.Height = height
    btn.Width = width

    'Should the button be hidden when created?
    If hidden = True Then
        btn.Hide()
    End If

    'Change the font
    If font = "Normal" Then
        btn.Font = setFont(btn.Font, "Consolas", 18)
    ElseIf font = "Small" Then
        btn.Font = setFont(btn.Font, "Consolas", 12)
    End If


    'Assign the Handlers and non-function variables
    btn.BackColor = Color.Gray
    btn.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None
    Me.Controls.Add(btn)
    AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf ButtonOnMouseClick
    AddHandler btn.MouseHover, AddressOf ButtonOnMouseHover
    AddHandler btn.MouseLeave, AddressOf ButtonOnMouseLeave
End Sub
```

So basically, it works like a charm when being used in this form. But when I've tried using it in a different form I realized that I had to create the same function again. This process would become tedious if I had to do it for each and every form. 
That's why I decided to create a new module called Public Functions in which I would have common functions shared by each module. The problem is that once it's created it cannot be executed because it returns an error that 'Controls.add' was not previously declared.

I do believe that this is something really simple. I've tried looking for the libraries which could be missing and I've tried importing System.Windows.Forms.Controls but I still get the same error.

How do I actually create a Public Function which can be shared between different forms?

Thanks in advance, Alex

Comment: You can pass in the Parent containers `.Controls` property and then this becomes a non-issue

Comment: There is no `Me`.  You'll need to add an extra argument of type Control.

Comment: @JayV can you give me an example in pseudo code?

Comment: @HansPassant I've tried adding a myControl as Control as an extra argument, but the error persists as 'Add' is not member of Control

Comment: That is accurate, it is a member of myControl.Controls

Comment: Right, thanks a lot. Still getting a hang of this!

Answer (score 0):

Sample code as requested:

**Method 1** Passing the `Controls` collection to your helper function.

```
Public Sub CreateNewButton(parentControls As ControlCollection,
                           font As String, x As Integer, y As Integer,
                           width As Integer, height As Integer,
                           name As String, text As String,
                           menu_type As Integer,
                           Optional hidden As Boolean = True,
                           Optional centered As Boolean = False)
    ' Abbreviated implementation to illustrate the point
    Dim newButton As New Button

    newButton.Top = y
    newButton.Left = x
    newButton.Name = name
    newButton.Text = text

    parentControls.Add(newButton)
End Sub
```

**Method 2** Passing the Parent container to your helper function.

```
Public Sub CreateNewButton(parent As Control,
                             font As String, x As Integer, y As Integer,
                             width As Integer, height As Integer,
                             name As String, text As String,
                             menu_type As Integer,
                             Optional hidden As Boolean = True,
                             Optional centered As Boolean = False)
    ' Abbreviated implementation to illustrate the point
    Dim newButton As New Button

    newButton.Top = y
    newButton.Left = x
    newButton.Name = name
    newButton.Text = text

    parent.Controls.Add(newButton)
End Sub
```

Screen shot of what it looks like.
* New 1 is from the first function
* New 2 is from the second function

These two functions can be called like this:

```
CreateNewButton(Me.Controls, "", 10, 10, 50, 20, "btnNew1", "New 1", 1)
CreateNewButton(Me, "", 100, 100, 50, 20, "btnNew2", "New 2", 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Create a class library(.DLL), say MyFunctionsLib.DLL which contains your functions and place it in the same folder of your new project folder (or in any sub folder).
When another new project is created, you add a reference to your 'DLL' file and you can access the functions.
In visual Studio 2017, File->New Project ->Visual Basic-> .NET Standard-> Class Library
and give a suitable name say MyFunctionsLib, click Ok

Eg.

```
Public NotInheritable Class MyFunctionsLib 
  Public Shared Function addTwoNums(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
  Return a+b
  End Function
End Class
```

Build your project and use your 'DLL' with any other project.